# ¿Como podria Reemplazar los strings en PHP?

Tags: php, html, string

Tengo una duda y es que no se como podría reemplazar una variable que esta dentro de una plantilla html y el valor de la variable estaría en un archivo externo php, Ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>El nombre de la persona es: <b>{nombre_persona}</b>.
</body>
</html>
```

la variable que quisiera reemplazar con php seria la que esta dentro de las llaves **{nombre_persona}** pero no se la forma en como hacerlo, quisiera ayuda de algun crack se lo agradeceria, estoy aprendiendo!

Comment: El **nombre_persona** es un valor que traerás desde php?

Comment: el valor lo traería desde un archivo externo php

Comment: Debes usar Ajax, con Jquery que seria lo más sencillo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes requerir el archivo donde este la variable con require o include.
Por ejemplo

```
require '../archivodondeestamivariable.php';
```

Luego ya deberías poder usar la variable si esta definida en tu archivo externo.

```
<?php
require 'misvaribles.php';//Archivo donde estan mis variables
echo $miVariableExterna;//Variable definida en mi archivo externo
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>El nombre de la persona es: <b><?php echo $miVariableExterna ?></b>.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo intentaré

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar Jquery por lo sencillo:

1-Agrega un id a tu etiqueta  por ejemplo:

```
<p>El nombre de la persona es: <b id="nombre"></b>.
```

2-Crea el Ajax

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'url_buscar_valor.php',
          success:  function (response) 
          {
              $("#nombre").html(response);                 
          }

     });
```

3-El valor de **url_buscar_valor** es la ruta de tu archivo, alli colocas un **echo** donde imprimas el valor del nombre.